# Update state from children component

Tags: reactjs

Take a look at the app. There is a list of buttons. It's really hard for me to explain the issue to you guys so take a look at the app yourself and consider this as a challenge. It's really a small app to demonstrate an issue that I am facing while working with react. This is not a basic stuff...

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-faraday-bxufk?file=/src/App.js

When clicking on the button, it is expected that the boolean next to it turn to false. It seems basic to you at first but when you take a look at the code, this is not easy to achieve. My real application is more complicated so I make a simple version of it just to demonstrate the issue

```
Expect:
Click on button 1 => boolean next to it turns to false
Click on button 2 => boolean next to it turns to false
Click on button 3 => boolean next to it turns to false

Reality:
Click on button 1 => screen goes blank
```

Comment: See this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-dream-00s75?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: You got the point. But here we want the tab to have dynamic content. It's not always button that's why we use the content props. Take a look at this example, my sandbox is the simpler version of it. You can see that the TabPane contains tab.content: https://ant.design/components/tabs/#components-tabs-demo-editable-card

Comment: This kind of forcing me to pass the content prop

Comment: [Updated Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-sound-x0ge3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Hmm professional here!! Thank you so so much!!!! Could you explain why does it work?

Comment: It's clever to use that function but I don't know why it works :)

Comment: Its just a normal function. You call it and it returns a `Button` component. One advantage of using a function is that you can pass dynamic content as parameters.

Comment: I mean why you know that we have to use content() instead of passing the component directly

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is related to state update. The handle button need to handle state as:

```
const handleButton = (id) => {
    console.log("On button click: ", id);

    setState((state) => {
      // Update isSaved of a corresponding button to false
      const updatedState = [...state];
      const updatedIndex = updatedState.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);

      updatedState[updatedIndex] = {
        ...updatedState[updatedIndex],
        isSaved: false
      };

      return updatedState;
    });
  };
```

The solution is actually in the `setState` variant which uses a `callback` like `setState((latestState) => {// do something })` and guarantees to give latest `state` for every execution.

Thanks for giving a beautiful problem to solve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your example does not work but it could be there is an error in my function

Comment: Sorry, but I have updated it. The only thing which was required to change the way to update state in `handleButton` function. Though I am still trying to figure out why your solution does not work...

Answer (score 0):

So, This is another way to solve this problem.

But first of all I will pin-down the problem in existing code, and try to explain why it is not working.

I had placed two `console.log` in `App.js` one is in `useEffect()` and another just before the `return` statement:

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);

  // Set pannels state
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect executing");

    setState(
      data.map((item) => ({
        id: item.id,
        isSaved: true,
        content: <Button id={item.id} handleButton={handleButton} />
      }))
    );
  }, []);

  const handleButton = (id) => {
   ....
   ....
  }

  console.log("App Rendering");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Try this</button>
      {state ? <Tab pannels={state} /> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And below is the console after execution:

[image]

Now it is clearly can be seen that when you are executing `setState` inside `useEffect` the `state` value is an empty array []. Because first render cycle of `App` is already completed and call to `useState` initialized `state` to empty array.

In `useEffect` you are assigning property `content` as:

```
...
content: <Button id={item.id} handleButton={handleButton} />
...
```

Now if you closely observe `{handleButton}` is an function bound to the first render of 'App' (which is of course a function in itself) and `{handleButton}` has access to `const state` in it's parent scope, which is an empty array [] in first render cycle of 'App';

Thus you are in the middle of pushing the `{handleButton}` in `state` which has still a value [] (empty array), while `useEffect` is executing.

As soon as `setState` completes inside `useEffect` another render cycle for `App` is executed (due to local state update react re-renders the component). A new instances of `App` and all of it's nested members are created, except the `state` and `setState` which are managed by the `react`.

After this second render of `App` your `state` now contains the reference of old instance of `{handleButton}` (where you assign property `content` to `Button`) of previous render of `App` thus these `{handleButton}` still have `state` value as [] (empty array closures).

Now when you click any of the `Button` it's `onClick` is bound to the old reference of `handleButton` which has `state` value as empty array, and thus when `{handleButton}` finishes execution it calls `setState` (function provided by react framework, not affected by re-render) it once again sets the `state` to an empty array. And you eventually get you buttons disappeared.

Now to solve this, you need to rebind new instance of `{handleButton}` each time a re-render happens for `App`. You can not memoize `{handleButton}` because it depends on the `state`. Thus you can delegate rendering of `Button` component to `Tab` which re-renders itself after every `state` update.

So you can do something like this:

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);

  // Set pannels state
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setState(
      data.map((item) => ({
        id: item.id,
        isSaved: true
      }))
    );
  }, []);

  const handleButton = (id) => {
    console.log("On button click: ", id);
    console.log(state);

    //Update isSaved of a corresponding button to false
    const updatedState = [...state];
    const updatedIndex = updatedState.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);

    updatedState[updatedIndex] = {
      ...updatedState[updatedIndex],
      isSaved: false
    };

    setState(updatedState);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => handleButton(2)}>Try this</button>
      {state ? <Tab pannels={state} handleButton={handleButton} /> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note: I have even used the same event handler `handleButton` for `try this` button too, to show that the same function instance works well if used on the component itself or passed to children.

**Tab.js**

```
const Tab = ({ pannels, handleButton }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      List of pannels
      {pannels.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <Button id={item.id} handleButton={handleButton} />
          <span>{item.isSaved ? "true" : "false"}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

codesandbox reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-pascal-o6ify

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your awesome solution. You got the point. But here we want the tab to have dynamic content. It's not always a button that's why we use the content props. Take a look at this example, my sandbox is the simpler version of it. You can see that the TabPane contains tab.content: https://ant.design/components/tabs/#components-tabs-demo-editable-card

Comment: Check @Yousaf 's comment above. I really appreciate your effort and it's awesome to have a developer just like you who's keen on sharing and solving the problem.

Comment: Fine, in that case my another answer (I had given two answers) is just okay for this problem.